# WordPress url rewriting pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have this link: http://localhost/?trips-page=2
And want it to be like this: http://localhost:90/trips-page/2

In my functions.php I have this

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^trips-page/?([^/]+)/?',
        '?trips-page=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
```

Also, here's my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^^trips-page/?([^/]+)/? /?trips-page=$matches[1] [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have re-saved permalink settings but it's not working. What am I missing?

Comment: You also need to add query vars, otherwise trips-page will never get populated. Also you don't need to change the htaccess. See here: http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/

Comment: When I add query vars it just shows me empty page.. @AntonyThompson